# Chatgpt API ERROR in python, i really dont know what to do

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, openai-api, chatgpt-api

ERROR

```
You tried to access openai.Completion, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0 - see the README at https://github.com/openai/openai-python for the API.

You can run `openai migrate` to automatically upgrade your codebase to use the 1.0.0 interface. 

Alternatively, you can pin your installation to the old version, e.g. `pip install openai==0.28`

A detailed migration guide is available here: https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742
```

code

```
`response = openai.Completion.create(model="text-davinci-003",
                                    prompt=f"Hello ",
                                    temperature=1,
                                    max_tokens=256,
                                    top_p=1,
                                    frequency_penalty=0,
                                    presence_penalty=0)`
```

I am using version 0.8 still to avoid the error, but i want to shift to newest model.
I havent read the docs.
So, can you please solve the code.
The error is in

````
openai.Completion.create
``` I guess
````

Comment: did you do any of the things suggested in the text? You say you haven't read the docs, now it's a good moment to do it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood in your error, you can :

You can upgrade your codebase to use the 1.0.0 interface.

```
openai migrate
```

and then try the older version :

```
pip install openai==0.28
```

try the suggested solutions then see what the cli prompts again.